# AWS recognition face API: Crop teeth section (mouth) from face

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, image-processing, aws-lambda

I'm cropping teeth section (mouth) from face based on x,y co-ordinates received from AWS recognition face API

this code is working and cropping the teeth section like

[image]

but I need only teeth section to be cropped.

1. AWS recognition API image response

   ```
    [
      {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.4604368805885315,
          "Height": 0.7760819792747498,
          "Left": 0.28602713346481323,
          "Top": 0.07381705939769745
        },
        "AgeRange": {
          "Low": 48,
          "High": 66
        },
        "Smile": {
          "Value": true,
          "Confidence": 99.91497802734375
        },
        "Eyeglasses": {
          "Value": false,
          "Confidence": 98.94174194335938
        },
        "Sunglasses": {
          "Value": false,
          "Confidence": 99.84471130371094
        },
        "Gender": {
          "Value": "Male",
          "Confidence": 99.57334899902344
        },
        "Beard": {
          "Value": false,
          "Confidence": 73.63420867919922
        },
        "Mustache": {
          "Value": false,
          "Confidence": 96.08769226074219
        },
        "EyesOpen": {
          "Value": true,
          "Confidence": 98.94685363769531
        },
        "MouthOpen": {
          "Value": true,
          "Confidence": 99.7721939086914
        },
        "Emotions": [
          {
            "Type": "HAPPY",
            "Confidence": 99.75701904296875
          },
          {
            "Type": "SURPRISED",
            "Confidence": 0.10713297128677368
          },
          {
            "Type": "CONFUSED",
            "Confidence": 0.056786004453897476
          },
          {
            "Type": "CALM",
            "Confidence": 0.02734198607504368
          },
          {
            "Type": "ANGRY",
            "Confidence": 0.020567195490002632
          },
          {
            "Type": "DISGUSTED",
            "Confidence": 0.01198340579867363
          },
          {
            "Type": "SAD",
            "Confidence": 0.011844608001410961
          },
          {
            "Type": "FEAR",
            "Confidence": 0.007329543586820364
          }
        ],
        "Landmarks": [
          {
            "Type": "eyeLeft",
            "X": 0.4020455777645111,
            "Y": 0.3627050220966339
          },
          {
            "Type": "eyeRight",
            "X": 0.6262026429176331,
            "Y": 0.379489928483963
          },
          {
            "Type": "mouthLeft",
            "X": 0.40419745445251465,
            "Y": 0.6104526519775391
          },
          {
            "Type": "mouthRight",
            "X": 0.5907381772994995,
            "Y": 0.6247860193252563
          },
          {
            "Type": "nose",
            "X": 0.49532997608184814,
            "Y": 0.48828810453414917
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftEyeBrowLeft",
            "X": 0.32399997115135193,
            "Y": 0.3045051097869873
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftEyeBrowRight",
            "X": 0.38662829995155334,
            "Y": 0.27300384640693665
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftEyeBrowUp",
            "X": 0.4492948651313782,
            "Y": 0.2880849540233612
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightEyeBrowLeft",
            "X": 0.578127920627594,
            "Y": 0.29742100834846497
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightEyeBrowRight",
            "X": 0.6459962725639343,
            "Y": 0.29183030128479004
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightEyeBrowUp",
            "X": 0.7144292593002319,
            "Y": 0.3330812454223633
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftEyeLeft",
            "X": 0.3629233241081238,
            "Y": 0.3603385388851166
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftEyeRight",
            "X": 0.4457237124443054,
            "Y": 0.36826738715171814
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftEyeUp",
            "X": 0.4013364613056183,
            "Y": 0.3494759500026703
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftEyeDown",
            "X": 0.40179359912872314,
            "Y": 0.37347349524497986
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightEyeLeft",
            "X": 0.5811655521392822,
            "Y": 0.3783351182937622
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightEyeRight",
            "X": 0.6668664813041687,
            "Y": 0.38298410177230835
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightEyeUp",
            "X": 0.6265660524368286,
            "Y": 0.36624279618263245
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightEyeDown",
            "X": 0.6238686442375183,
            "Y": 0.39007559418678284
          },
          {
            "Type": "noseLeft",
            "X": 0.4562915861606598,
            "Y": 0.5203639268875122
          },
          {
            "Type": "noseRight",
            "X": 0.5394821166992188,
            "Y": 0.5265129804611206
          },
          {
            "Type": "mouthUp",
            "X": 0.4932428300380707,
            "Y": 0.5806143283843994
          },
          {
            "Type": "mouthDown",
            "X": 0.48947831988334656,
            "Y": 0.6564671397209167
          },
          {
            "Type": "leftPupil",
            "X": 0.4020455777645111,
            "Y": 0.3627050220966339
          },
          {
            "Type": "rightPupil",
            "X": 0.6262026429176331,
            "Y": 0.379489928483963
          },
          {
            "Type": "upperJawlineLeft",
            "X": 0.28082960844039917,
            "Y": 0.37847602367401123
          },
          {
            "Type": "midJawlineLeft",
            "X": 0.3077985942363739,
            "Y": 0.6443988680839539
          },
          {
            "Type": "chinBottom",
            "X": 0.48529136180877686,
            "Y": 0.7894702553749084
          },
          {
            "Type": "midJawlineRight",
            "X": 0.7061411738395691,
            "Y": 0.6732134819030762
          },
          {
            "Type": "upperJawlineRight",
            "X": 0.77140212059021,
            "Y": 0.4138971269130707
          }
        ],
        "Pose": {
          "Roll": 3.0064163208007812,
          "Yaw": -2.569990634918213,
          "Pitch": 8.883845329284668
        },
        "Quality": {
          "Brightness": 76.55046844482422,
          "Sharpness": 94.08262634277344
        },
        "Confidence": 99.99818420410156
      }
    ]
   ```

   2. Node Js code for crop using gm ImageMagick library

   ```
   const init  = async () => {
   try {
       console.info("Process Started");
       const size = await getImageSize("passport-photo.jpeg");
       console.info("get Image Size: ", size);
       const faceDetails = await getFaceDetailsFromImage();

       // Uploded image width height
       const imageWidth = size.width;
       const imageHeight = size.height;

       // Face detail width height
       const faceDetailWidth =  Math.round(faceDetails[0].BoundingBox.Width * imageWidth);
       const faceDetailHeight =  Math.round(faceDetails[0].BoundingBox.Height * imageHeight);

       // Coordinates for the mouth
       const faceDetailMouthLeft = faceDetails[0].Landmarks.filter(o => o.Type === "mouthLeft");
       const faceDetailMouthRight = faceDetails[0].Landmarks.filter(o => o.Type === "mouthRight");
       const faceDetailMouthUp = faceDetails[0].Landmarks.filter(o => o.Type === "mouthUp");
       const faceDetailMouthDown = faceDetails[0].Landmarks.filter(o => o.Type === "mouthDown");

       // Find x and y point from where the cropping needs to be started
       const xPoint = Math.round(faceDetailMouthLeft[0].X * imageWidth);
       const yPoint = Math.round(faceDetailMouthUp[0].Y * imageHeight);

       // Width height for which image needs to be cut from start index

       const width = ((faceDetailMouthRight[0].X - faceDetailMouthLeft[0].X) * imageWidth)
       const height = ((faceDetailMouthDown[0].Y - faceDetailMouthUp[0].Y) * imageHeight)

       console.log("xPoint:" + xPoint + ", yPoint:" + yPoint + ", faceDetailWidth:" + faceDetailWidth + ", faceDetailHeight:" + faceDetailHeight)
       gm('passport-photo.jpeg')

       // Invoke crop function 
       .crop(width, height, xPoint, yPoint, true) 

       // Process and Write the image 
       .write("crop5.png", function (err) {
           console.error(err);
           if (!err) console.log('done'); 
       }); 

   } catch (error){
       console.error(error);
   }
   }
   init();
   ```

original image

[image]

Comment: Can you add some debug code and tell us the values it extracted for `xPoint`, `yPoint`, `width` and `height`?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein thanks for your response, i added debug code and here are the values.
xPoint:90, yPoint:129, width:41.598581194877625, height:16.915176928043365

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I attached original image above as well.

Comment: Why have you added `true` at the end of the crop command? Can you point us to some documentation that explains it?

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein for pointing to `true` flag, by passing true it accepts the parameter as a percentage value, so by remove true its working fine now. Thanks for your help.

Another question I have: Is there any way in this code so we can use padding or margin type things on cordinates points? I want some more area to be visible after crop?

Comment: Sure, just add/subtract a few pixels before cropping. I suggest you do it _after_ multiplying by `imageWidth` and `imageHeight`, so the values are in pixels.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have posted another issue related with crop jimp library
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196003/fix-image-orientation-in-jimp
please share your idea if any, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations for the mouth co-ordinates appear to be correct.

However, I see you are using:

```
.crop(width, height, xPoint, yPoint, true)
```

As you say, this "accepts the parameter as a percentage value", which probably isn't what you want.