# Fix image orientation in Jimp

Tags: node.js, image-processing, jimp

I am using Jimp (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) library to crop the image.

Crop is working fine but I only have an issue with image orientation.

Sometimes, user uploaded rotated images and its result rotated cropped images.

I went through with https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp documentation but couldn't find anything related to this.

Here are couple of links I went through but didn't helped:

https://justmarkup.com/articles/2019-10-21-image-orientation/

[Accessing JPEG EXIF rotation data in JavaScript on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

So, long story short: jimp correctly reads images rotated via exif orientation property and rearranges the pixels as if the exif/orientation property didn't exist, but then also stores the old exif property instead of resetting it to 1 as it should for it to be displayed properly on every device.

The simplest solution I was able to implement was using [exif-auto-rotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif-auto-rotate) to rotate the image pixels and reset the exif property on the frontend before uploading the (base64 encoded) image to the backend:

```
    import Rotator from 'exif-auto-rotate';
    
    // ...
    
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    
    const image = await Rotator.createRotatedImageAsync(file, "base64")
        .catch(err => {
            if (err === "Image is NOT have a exif code" || err === "Image is NOT JPEG") {
                // just return base64 encoded image if image is not jpeg or contains no exif orientation property
                return toBase64(file)
            }
            // reject if other error
            return Promise.reject(err)
        });
```

If you need to do this on the backend then you are probably better off using [jpeg-autorotate](https://github.com/johansatge/jpeg-autorotate) with buffers as suggested [here](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/733#issuecomment-494593925):

```
const fileIn = fs.readFileSync('input.jpg')
const jo = require('jpeg-autorotate')
const {buffer} = await jo.rotate(fileIn, {quality: 30})
const image = await Jimp.read(buffer)
```

More info on browser-based exif orientation issues:

[EXIF Orientation Handling Is a Ghetto](https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/)

Answer (score 0):

just change the jimp version to

```
"jimp": "0.8.5",
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.